# ruby on rails - validation in nested class shows the error screen on failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I currently have a problem with a simple validation.
On saving my model this validation is ran.

A user has multiple questions, questions have multiple answers

This validates statement is part of my joined table class

```
validates :answers, length: { maximum: 6 }
```

The answer will be the one updated, so I ask the question to validate itself

```
validates_associated :user_question
```

This validation is failed correctly when the number of answers selected exceeds 6.
However, instead of returning to my form. It shows me a big error message stating that the validation has failed.

I would like to display these problems on the form so the user knows what's wrong.

Other validation errors for the form are displaying as intended. It's just this nested attribute that is causing problems for some reason.

This is the error that is being shown

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid

Validation failed: User question is invalid
```

On the following line: @user.attributes=(user_params)

That's indeed the moment when it validates (I think), but it is too abstracted to see what is wrong with the validation exactly (If there is anything wrong).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post the error itself. Are you sure the "validation failed" and not that the validation is incorrect and caused an error to be raised?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I updated the question.
It does specify that it failed - Validation failed: User question is invalid

Answer (score 0):

how about if add this custom validation, this inside your question.rb (class)

```
validate :maximum_six_answer

private

def maximum_six_answer
  if answers.size > 6
    errors.add :base, "sorry maximum six answers"
  end
end
```

Comment: This gave me the same result. I also tried it with a custom method before. However, I didn't use the :base name then. Could it be that this messes up because the user is being saved? Since this question form is a 'fields_for' inside the form for the user.

Answer (score 0):

The `validates_associated` statement will do two things:

1. run validations on the named association, populating `errors` on that associated object
2. log an error on the association itself so that the validating object will also be considered invalid.

So the details of why your question is invalid should be available from `@user.user_question.errors`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I shall try it out and experiment a bit and come back later with some results.

Comment: So it looks like, when I run validations like that and directly make changes to the joined table of the user's questions, the validation correctly passes through as an error that I can display on the view. However, this means that validates_associated makes it so that it forces the invalidrecord error, instead of showing it on the view. That's my theory so far.